# Why is my conftest fixture is not applying to all FastAPI tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, fixtures

#### conftest.py

```
import pytest
from ...main import app as starter
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="module")
def client():
    client = TestClient(starter)
    return client
```

#### test_main.py

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.unit
def test_root(client):
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.json() == {"message": "Hello Bigger Applications!"}
```

#### test_router.py

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.unit
class TestHelloRouter:
    def test_hello(client):
        response = client.get("/hello")
        assert response.json() == {"message": "Hello Router!"}


@pytest.mark.unit
class TestUserRouter:
    def test_read_users(client):
        response = client.get("/users/")
        assert response.json() == [{"username": "Rick"}, {"username": "Morty"}]

    def test_read_user_me(client):
        response = client.get("/users/me")
        assert response.json() == {"username": "fakecurrentuser"}

    def test_read_user(client):
        username = "unit-test"
        response = client.get(f"/users/{username}")
        assert response.json() == {"username": username}
```

Why am I receiving this error for all the tests in the test_router.py file? Should the fixture scope of client be session, and should autouse be set to true?

```
E       AttributeError: 'TestUserRouter' object has no attribute 'get'
E       AttributeError: 'TestHelloRouter' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these are classes, it looks like to me that you are just missing `self` as the first argument to your functions under test.

```py
mport pytest


@pytest.mark.unit
class TestHelloRouter:
    def test_hello(self, client):
        response = client.get("/hello")
        assert response.json() == {"message": "Hello Router!"}


@pytest.mark.unit
class TestUserRouter:
    def test_read_users(self, client):
        response = client.get("/users/")
        assert response.json() == [{"username": "Rick"}, {"username": "Morty"}]

    def test_read_user_me(self, client):
        response = client.get("/users/me")
        assert response.json() == {"username": "fakecurrentuser"}

    def test_read_user(self, client):
        username = "unit-test"
        response = client.get(f"/users/{username}")
        assert response.json() == {"username": username}
```

Comment: thank you for saving my brainfart